Accessing a component's "enabled" property through an interface
I have a class / behavior MyBehavior that looks on the game object for any component that implements the interface IMyInterface using this code:  myInterface = (IMyInterface)gameObject.GetComponentInParent (typeof(IMyInterface)).
IMyInterface is implemented by multiple classes / behaviors. For example:
public class MyClass1: MonoBehaviour, IMyInterface

public class MyClass2: MonoBehaviour, IMyInterface

etc etc.
I would like to be able to determine whether the MyClass1, MyClass2 etc components are enabled or disabled.
I'm not sure how to access the components however, and interfaces don't seem to have access to the enabled and disabled properties.
One solution I've thought about is to check the type explicitly e.g. myInterface is MyClass1 but this has the problem that if I ever make a new class that implements the interface I'd have to remember to come back to this MyBehavior script and update it too, which I don't like.
Are there any ways I can get the type of the class the interface is on, and access its enabled or disabled properties?   Would casting it as Monobehaviour work be OK if i always expect it to be a Monobehaviour, or is that a bad idea with hidden issues?

You don't. In terms of type definitions your IMyInterface is not a Unity's GameObject nor it's a MonoBehaviour class. If i understood correctly, you want to extend some of the scripts with a common behavior and then differentiate in those scripts. In that case you may want to consider a 'base-scriptlikepublic class MyGeneralBehaviour : MonoBehaviourand then implement your classes from that:public class MyClass1: MyGeneralBehaviour`. Doing so, you'll be able to access the underlying properties of transform and objects. Or, you can go into the field of covariance and contravariance

That doesn't work because MyClass1 and MyClass2 are totally unrelated, they just both implement a common interface and the MyBehavior component operates on anything that implements that interface.

But they are related, they both implement IMyInterface by your idea, so they have to have some methods in common

Right but it doesn't make sense for them to inherit from the same class.  Sharing an interface is sharing a common contract, not sharing functionality necessarily.  This approach is not correct.

Well you want them to share functionality, no? You want this interface to have access to a fields or properties defined in GameObject/MonoBehaviour/etc? Therefore, you want them to share functionality. Otherwise, it is logically impossible, because as i've stated, the IMyInterface is not GameObject because it doesn't inherit it, and so, you can't assume it is, and access it's properties without an appropriate operator like is

No, I don't want them to share functionality.  I just want them to share a contract, those are not the same thing.  I don't want the interface to have access to the fields, I want to think about ways to get access in other means like in the examples I gave already which do accomplish it in some ways.  I'm wondering if there are better solutions.  In fact, one of my examples is kind of a parallel to yours , just using MonoBehaviour as MyGeneralBehavior,.

They both inherit from MonoBehavior anyway so both already have the enabled property anyway .. you could of course simply let the interface define it as well bool enabled { get; set; } should probably do the trick .. or if not just make your own property and for those that inherit from MonoBehaviour you can simply forward to the built-in enabled

Would casting it as Monobehaviour work be OK if i always expect it to be a Monobehaviour, or is that a bad idea with hidden issues? as you use GetComponentInParent it is basically almost given that these will be always MonoBehaviour (as usually none of us directly inherits from Component) .. general I'd say you do whatever works for you .. personally if the state is required for the interface I would directly have a property in the interface then

If you are allowed to change IMyInterface, it is this simple:
public interface IMyInterface {
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}

Even if you apply an interface to a derived type in a class hierarchy, this interface can still expose any of the members that are part of that class interface, doesn't matter how far up in the inheritance chain they are.
So this way you can ensure access to the original enabled property of MonoBehaviour (actually, its parent, Behaviour) class.

If you aren't allowed to change IMyInterface, then yes, cast to MonoBehaviour or Behaviour instead of casting to a concrete type.
IMyInterface myInterface = ...
MonoBehaviour myBehaviour = (MonoBehaviour)myInterface;

This is definitely not a bad practice because here you already are within MonoBehaviour paradigm by using gameObject.GetComponentInParent. This obviously won't work with C# classes, neither will this work with ScriptableObjects or other types that are not in the hierarchy of MonoBehaviour. So you are safe here.

Comparing two approaches: as you already use interfaces, it is better to expose the property there instead of casting everything.

Edit: basically, this is what @derhugo described in the comments. I should have probably read them all first

Excellent, thanks, I didn't know I could just expose the property that trivially :)  And appreciate the comments re: Monobehavior casting, you and @derHugo are right that's a good razor to use to decide when it's ok to do so. I'll go ahead and add the property to the interface just so I can have an example and remind myself if something similar comes up again.

Just sidenote: public keyword is redundant within an interface. Another advantage of the interface would be that you can expose the enabled state as read-only in the interface so it is a bit saver against being set from the outside
